# jQuery Flot - Points not showing on graph in IE

Tags: jquery, flot

I have been struggling with this for a while, but I can't seem to figure it out.

If you look at the jsFiddle below in Chrome, the points on the graph are visable, but if you look at the same Fiddle in IE9 they are not there. I have simplified the data to just 2 points.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D4M4A/

Code below:

```
$(function () {

var dataset = [
    { label: "% Personal Impact", data: [[1352937600000,68]], lines: { show: true } },
    { label: "# Responses", data: [[1352937600000,8]], yaxis: 2}    
];


$.plot($("#placeholder"),
    dataset,
    {
       yaxes: [ { max: 101, min: -0.1, tickSize: 20 }, { position: "right", min: -0 } ],
       xaxes: [ { mode: "time", minTickSize: [1, "day"], min: new Date('2012, 11, 01').getTime() } ],
       series: {
       lines: { show: true },
       points: { show: true }
    },
       grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true }
});


});
```

Appreciate any help.

Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, the issue was to do with the way different browsers Date() constructors work.

There is a comprehensive list of which date formats work in which browser here:

http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html

Turns out only a couple of date formats are guaranteed to work across all browsers, the one I was using isn't one of them.

I ended up using dateString 2009/07/12

Thanks

Comment: It's always worthwhile to be explicit in your answer - what was the format that you settled on that works across all browsers?